# having issues with "dfx start" and "dfx deploy" code

Tags: internet-computer, dfinity

Does anyone know the solution to this? I am new to this and learning. I am on Macbook Air m1.

1. This is the end code while running `dfx start` in the terminal:

> thread 'replica-actor' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Cannot start the replica: Timeout', src/dfx/src/actors/replica.rs:279:78
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

2. This is what happens while running `dfx deploy` in terminal:

> Error: An error happened during communication with the replica: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/status): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 61)

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: May you share us your dfx version ? You can get it by typing `dfx -V`.

Comment: dfx version is 0.9.3

Comment: May you try with [dfx 0.11.0](https://github.com/dfinity/sdk/releases/tag/0.11.0) ?

Comment: I tried it, but the problems still continue.

Comment: Is your dfx project open-source ? Likewise we could try and possibly debug on our own.

Comment: I dont know whether its open-source or not. how do you check that ?

Comment: "Open-source software (OSS) is computer software that is released under a license in which the copyright holder grants users the rights to use, study, change, and distribute the software and its source code to anyone and for any purpose." Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software)
So if you created every component of the project and you're fine with distributing it on GitHub, please share the GitHub repository link otherwise ask the persons who did the components of your project.

Comment: the code is basic hello of dfinity, i.e., "dfx new hello". I am just starting with this and this problems occurred with the basic hello file that dfinity itself has made.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison dfx is open source: https://github.com/dfinity/sdk and is Dfinity's sdk for their distributed ledger computing and hosting platform ICP.

Comment: @AshtonEngberg I know that Dfinity's SDK is on GitHub, I've been working for Dfinity. I was requesting Niell_ray28 to share his code if it was open-source in order to have [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Apologies, totally misread that comment earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. I was running the code while it was stored in an external drive. When I created the same folder on my desktop and ran everything the same way,  the problem got solved and I no longer have those errors in my terminal. I don't know how it is happening, but I just discovered it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try "dfx start --emulator"